# Cannot get selector of inherited functions

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x, function-selector

```
contract A {
    uint256 x;
    function myFunc(uint256 _x) public {
        x = _x;
    }
}

contract B is A {
    function myFunc1(uint256 _x) public {
        x = _x;
    }

}

contract Test {
    constructor() {
        A.myFunc.selector; // works
        B.myFunc1.selector; // works
        B.myFunc.selector; // doesn't work
    }
}
```

If I have a contract `B` that inherits from contract `A` I would expect that I would be able to get a function selector for an inherited function, just as I would be able to call `B(_addr).myFunc()` on the inherited contract. But instead I get this error on compilation:

```
TypeError: Member "myFunc" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(contract B).
  --> contracts/A.sol:23:9:
   |
23 |         B.myFunc.selector; // doesn't work
   |         ^^^^^^
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is the case?

Comment: Just figured out passing an address to `B` works, so `B(_addr).myFunc.selector` but the question above still stands

Answer (score 0):

This works in Remix:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.17;

contract A {
    uint256 x;
    function myFunc(uint256 _x) public {
        x = _x;
    }
}

contract B is A {
    function myFunc1(uint256 _x) public {
        x = _x;
    }

}

// Defining calling contract
contract Test {
    constructor() {
        // Creating child contract object
        B b = new B(); 
        A.myFunc.selector; // works
        B.myFunc1.selector; // works
        b.myFunc.selector; // works
    }
}
```

The issue is that you need to create the child contract object in the calling contract before you can call the `myFunc` function originally defined in the parent contract.